# Subplot using matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date

Tags: python, pandas, subplot

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import csv 
import datetime 

timestamp1 = []
for t in ts_temp1:
    timestamp1.append(mdates.datestr2num(t))
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b-%d')

plt.plot_date(timestamp1,xgtemp1,'r.',label='X GALVO 1',lw=2)
plt.plot_date(timestamp1,ygtemp1,'b.',label='Y GALVO 1',lw=2)

ax = plt.gcf().axes[0] 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)
plt.ylabel('Galvo Temperatures (°C)')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to create a subplot with 3 rows and 1 column of plots.
I have 3 blocks of "plotting" code identical to the one above.
The goal is to have all the plots within the subplot to share the same x-axis.
I'm unsure how to approach this subplot as my many previous attempts haven't worked at all.

Sidenote: I've tried plotting with other methods but this is the only one that correctly plots the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)

ax1.plot_date(timestamp1,xgtemp1,'r.',label='X GALVO 1',lw=2)
ax1.plot_date(timestamp1,ygtemp1,'b.',label='Y GALVO 1',lw=2)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)

ax.set_ylabel('Galvo Temperatures (°C)')
ax.grid()
ax.legend(loc='upper right')

fig.show()
```

I think it is better to work directly with the `Axes` objects (`ax1`, `ax2`, `ax3`) instead of getting pyplot to figure it out or extracting the current `Axes` and `Figure` objects. For your other subplots use `ax2` and `ax3` or do this instead:

`fig, axn = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)`

and loop over `axn`.

Also, if you're using pandas anyways you can replace the `plot_date` commands with `df['column'].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2)` and skip the time stamp prep work.